# How to bulk update mongoDB in Rust by inserting full doc if entry doesn't exist and updating select fields if entry exists?

Tags: rust

In short, I am interested in finding the most optimal, minimal call amount way of executing this pseudocode logic:

```
match find(doc) {
    Some(x) => x.update(select_fields),
    None=>collection.insert(all_fields)
}
```

but in bulk, for the entire local DB, without iterating one by one. Is there such a method? What's the most minimal one currently available?

My use case:

I have a `HashMap<T,MyStruct>`. I've packed both key and value into the `doc!{}`. Is that okay?

For some reason I was getting error trait `From<u64>` is not implemented for `Bson` in `key3`, so I changed my code to `f64`:

```
let dmp_op = my_database.lock().unwrap().clone();
let mut dmp_db = vec![];
for (k,v) in dmp_op{
    dmp_db.push(doc! { "key": value, "key2": value2, "key3": value3 as f64 },
    )
};
match collection.insert_many(dmp_db, None).await{
    Ok(x)=>x,
    Err(x)=>{
        println!("{:?}",x);
        continue
    }
};
```

This part works, but that's non-repeatable. Instead of doing this, I'd love to execute the aforementioned logic in the most optimal way from scratch.

I can't find any information as to whether all the singular methods I used in an implementation of `find_one_and_update()` + `upsert` can be used in bulk.

PS: On second thought... maybe my infra logic is flawed? Just starting with MongoDB, what is more preferable:

1. Inserting/Updating one by one inside worker threads into MongoDB instead of local HashMap
2. Creating a separate thread that from time to time inserts into MongoDB the local HashMap / cleanses it to keep low resource?

Comment: I think the rust mongodb driver is flawed in the sense that it doesn't support the bulkWrite API. This seems to be an active decision made by the team. It was also supported in their prototype i believe. Unfortunately it is very limiting for large upserts since you need one request per upsert.